# drop down does not show value and text asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I have two tables States and Cities

with two dropdown list that when the state drop down selected the options should be available on Cities dropdown list but somehow Text and Value doesn't appear

State ViewBag and DropDown List

```
ViewBag.State = new SelectList(db.StateRepository.GetAll(), "StateId", "StateTitle");
@Html.DropDownList("States",(SelectList)ViewBag.State, "Please Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id="State"})
```

City Drop down

```
<select class="form-control" id="City">    </select>
```

Json in Controller

```
  public ActionResult GetCities(int id)
  {

            var data = db.Cities.Where(d => d.StateId == id).Select(d => new { Text = d.CityTitle, Value = d.CityId });
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Script

```
 $("#State").change(function() {
        var loading = $('<option></option>').text("Please Wait");
        $('#City').attr("disabled", "disabled").empty().append(loading);

        $.getJSON("/GetCities/" + $("#State > option:selected").attr("value"),
            function(result) {
                $("#City").removeAttr("disabled").empty().append($("<option></option)").val("").text("Please Select"));
                    $.each(result,
                        function(item) {
                            $("#City").append($("<option></option>").val(item.value).text(item.text));
                        });
                });
  });
```

By not showing the value and Text I mean like I have 4 Cities for 'x' State on my table,
in the view when I change the StateDropDown to 'x' State it just shows 4 empty `<option></option>` in my City DropDown list without any text and value

Guys I really appreciate all your help I'm newbie and I have no idea what the problem is so please help.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think the results returned from the controller is returning an object like:

```
[{ "Text": "..", "Value": ".." }]
```

So you would want to bind:

```
$.each(result, function(item) {
    $("#City").append($("<option></option>").val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
});
```

The Value and Text should be upper-cased.

Comment: No in my code it's correct, its because of my final edit. i dont know what the goddamn problem is please review the code again. tnx

Comment: Check out my edit.  I think item.value and item.text should be item.Value and item.Text